# what this signifies <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="jakarta.tags.core" %> in jsp file under src root folder src/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp?

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I'm following a video where tutor added the above line to see result on jsp from controller after writing model.addAttribute("", ); and mentioned JSTL tags and jasper for rendering in dependency file. He also changed form @restcontroller to @controller to pick the home.jsp file.

I just wanted to know the purpose of above line and how it helps.

Comment: Just read authoritative documentation instead of unauthoritative videos: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaiy.html & https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalj.html